# Nested switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible to use nested `switch` statement in javascript.

My code is some what look like

```
switch(id1)
{
case 1:
     switch(id2){
     case 1:{
        switch(id3){
        case 1:{}
        case 2:{}
        }
    }
     case 2:{
        switch(id4){
        case 1:{}
        case 2:{}
        }
     }
}
case 2:
}
```

If yes then it is a good practice to do or we can use any alternate approach.

Comment: it makes no sense to switch with the same variable.

Comment: I can say that without any doubt, this is not clean code. That said, the best approach depends on what it's actually about.

Comment: @NinaScholz I assume that it was pseudocode.

Comment: It should be *possible* (don't forget break statements). Recommended -- maybe not.

Comment: Yes it is a pseudocode. I am planning to write code and as requirement I am prepare for code.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely fine.

You can make the `switch` nesting less complex by using `switch (true)`:

```
switch (true) {
  case ((id1 === 1) && (id2 === 1) && (id3 === 1)) :
  case ((id1 === 1) && (id2 === 1) && (id3 === 2)) :
  case ((id1 === 1) && (id2 === 2) && (id3 === 1)) :
  case ((id1 === 1) && (id2 === 2) && (id3 === 2)) :
  case ((id1 === 2) && (id2 === 1) && (id3 === 1)) :
  case ((id1 === 2) && (id2 === 1) && (id3 === 2)) :
  case ((id1 === 2) && (id2 === 2) && (id3 === 1)) :
  case ((id1 === 2) && (id2 === 2) && (id3 === 2)) :
}
```

Comment: you can omit the parenthesis in the case clauses.

Comment: Force of habit, Nina. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use inner switch like this way,

### Please check this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/1qsfropn/3/

```
var text;
var date = new Date()
switch (date.getDay()) {
 case 1:
 case 2:
 case 3:
 default:
    text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
    break;
 case 4:
 case 5:
    text = "Soon it is Weekend";
    break;
 case 0:
 case 6:
      switch(date.getFullYear()){
      case 2015:
        text = "It is Weekend of last Year.";
      break;
      case 2016:
        text = "It is Weekend of this Year.";
      break;
      case 2017:
        text = "It is Weekend of next Year.";
      break;
      default:
      text = date.getDay();
      break;
    }
break;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;`
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a nested switch statement but that can quickly become a spaghetti code and therefore it is not recommended. I would rather use functions with the nested switch statement for code clearance or maybe use recursive function depending on what the code is supposed to do.

This is only a pseudo-code but I hope it gives you some idea on how to implement it. You have to be carefull to make the recursion stop on some given value of the ID. 
This pseudo-code increments the value of the ID by 1 if the value of the ID is 1, and increments by 2 if the value is 2. If the value is not 1 or 2 the recursion ends.

```
function recursiveSwitch(var id) {
    switch(id) {
       case 1: 
           recursiveSwitch(id + 1);
           break;
       case 2
          recursiveSwitch(id + 2)
          break;
       default:
          return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's possible but I think it depends on the complexity of the nesting if it's recommended to use *nested switch statement* or to use *functions with the nested switch statement* as Ómar Óskarsson has suggested.

Comment: This is not really an answer, you're just confirming Omar's answer

Comment: @Shogunivar No! Actually I say it depends on the complexity!