# Avoid nested switch case in Node JS

Tags: nodes

I have a scenario wherein I have to use a nested if-else if, to avoid that I opted for using nested switch case. I would like to know if this will be a proper way to do this? Is there any better way to achieve this? Pls let me know. Thanks in advance

```
let message = "";

switch (season) {
    case 'Summer':
        switch(Summer) {
            case 'April' :
            message = "season summer and month April"
            break;
            case 'May' :
            message = "season summer and month May"
            break;
        }
    case 'Monsoon':
        switch(Monsoon) {
            case 'July' :
            message = "season Monsoon and month July"
            break;
            case 'August' :
            message = "season Monsoon and month August"
            break;
        }
    case 'Spring':
        switch(Spirng) {
            case 'XX' :
            message = "season Spring and month XX"
            break;
            case 'YY' :
            message = "season Spring and month YY"
            break;
        }
    case 'Autumn':
        switch(Autumn) {
            case 'XYZ' :
            message = "season Spring and month XYZ"
            break;
            case 'PQM' :
            message = "season Spring and month PQM"
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370979/nested-switch-statement-in-javascript) : you can avoid nested switch case

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it more simple by making below change

```
case 'Monsoon':
                message = "season Monsoon and month "+ Monsoon 
                break;
case 'Spring':
                message = "season Spring and month "+ Spring
                break;
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: thanks for the response. My scenario is I will receive two inputs for e.g. season and month like req("Summer","June") OR req("Summer","April"). Now considering both these options I will have to show the exact month & season.