# How can a nested switch be avoided in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, nested, switch-statement

I'm looking down the barrel of a nested switch statement. I would really like to avoid this rats nest. I know in other languages there are other funky ways of avoiding this, like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370979/nested-switch-statement-in-javascript), how about Dart?

My data structure is quite complex compared to this, so here is something simple & similar.

```
enum DayOfWeek {
sun,
mon,
tues,
wed,
thurs,
fri,
sat,
}

enum WeekOfMonth {
/// 1-7
first,
/// 8-14
second,
/// 15-21
third,
/// 22-28
fourth,
/// 29-31
fifth,
}

switch (dayOfWeek) {
  case sun:
    switch (weekOfMonth) {
      case first:
      
      case second:

      case third:

      case fourth:

      case fifth:

    }

  case mon:

    ...

  case tues:

  case wed:

  case thurs:

  case fri:

  case sat:
}
```

Comment: I would say it also highly depends on what you do inside the cases. Does every single inner case do something different?

Comment: In this specific case yes each nested case was doing something different, this was partly why it was driving me nuts. It's just so ugly, unreadable & disorganized looking... ended up changing my entire structure so I didn't have to do this... but I would like to see any other approaches if you have any.

Answer (score 3):

You will always have some sort of nesting, unless there is a logic on what you want to return - e.g. if 1st week, always return 'abc'...

I found recently that a simple way to achieve this is to use a Map instead of case statement.

Not saying I would always recommend this, but this is an approach you might use in some cases.

In a Map you simply store your return values like this

```
enum DayOfWeek {
sun,
mon,
tues,
wed,
thurs,
fri,
sat,
}

enum WeekOfMonth {
/// 1-7
first,
/// 8-14
second,
/// 15-21
third,
/// 22-28
fourth,
/// 29-31
fifth,
}

String? f(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, WeekOfMonth weekOfMonth) {
  
  var ret = <DayOfWeek, Map<WeekOfMonth, String>> {
    DayOfWeek.sun: {
          WeekOfMonth.first: "Sun - 1st",
          WeekOfMonth.second: "Sun - 2nd",
          WeekOfMonth.third: "Sun - 3rd",
          WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Sun - 4th",
          WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Sun - 5th",
         },
     DayOfWeek.mon: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Mon - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Mon - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Mon - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Mon - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Mon - 5th",
       },
       DayOfWeek.tues: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Tues - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Tues - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Tues - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Tues - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Tues - 5th",
       },
       DayOfWeek.wed: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Wed - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Wed - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Wed - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Wed - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Wed - 5th",
       },
       DayOfWeek.thurs: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Thurs - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Thurs - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Thurs - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Thurs - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Thurs - 5th",
       },
       DayOfWeek.fri: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Fri - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Fri - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Fri - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Fri - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Fri - 5th",
       },
       DayOfWeek.sat: {
        WeekOfMonth.first: "Sat - 1st",
        WeekOfMonth.second: "Sat - 2nd",
        WeekOfMonth.third: "Sat - 3rd",
        WeekOfMonth.fourth: "Sat - 4th",
        WeekOfMonth.fifth: "Sat - 5th",
       },         
  };
  
  return ret[dayOfWeek]![weekOfMonth];
  
  
}

void main() {
  print(f(DayOfWeek.wed, WeekOfMonth.third));
}
```

Comment: Very interesting way of doing it. Will keep this one up my sleeve if i need such madness again, thanks for the input. I restructured to not need the nested switches :)